# вспомогательный класс auto_ptr_ref

Tags: c++

Для чего нужен был вспомогательный класс auto_ptr_ref. Нужны примеры простейшей реализации и использования.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto_ptr_ref` - пример попытки "красивой" реализации семантики перемещения (move semantics) средствами языка С++98. Стандартный `std::auto_ptr`, как известно, должен *перемещать* право владения памятью при копировании (как конструктором копирования, так и оператором присваивания)

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pa(new int(42)); // `pa` владеет памятью
std::auto_ptr<int> pb = pa;         // теперь `pb` владеет памятью, `pa` пуст
pa = pb;                            // теперь `pa` владеет памятью, `pb` пуст
```

Но это создает определенные трудности при реализации всех форм копирования для  `std::auto_ptr`. Так как копирование модифицирует свою правую часть, параметры конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания по идее должны быть *неконстантными ссылками* на `std::auto_ptr`. Но в этом случае мы не сможем делать что-то вроде

```
std::auto_ptr<int> foo() { ... }
...
std::auto_ptr<int> p = foo();
```

т.к. функция `foo()` возвращает временный объект, а неконстантные ссылки нельзя привязывать ко временным объектам. Что делать?

---

Рассмотрим проблему на отвлеченном примере. Предположим, что мы захотели реализовать некий класс `S`, хранящий некое целочисленное значение и перемещающий это значение в получателя (в левую часть) при копировании. Правая часть при копировании получает значение `-1`

```
struct S 
{
  int i;

  S(int i = -1) : i(i) 
    {}

  S(S &s) : i(s.i)
    { s.i = -1; }

  S &operator =(S &s)
  {
    i = s.i;
    s.i = -1;
    return *this;
  } 
};
```

У нас получилось то, что надо

```
S a(42);
assert(a.i == 42);

S b = a;
assert(b.i == 42 && a.i == -1);

a = b;
assert(a.i == 42 && b.i == -1);
```

Однако мы не можем пользоваться нашим классом вот так

```
S foo() { return S(42); }
...
S a = foo(); // ERROR

S b;
b = foo(); // ERROR
```

по причине того, что неконстантную ссылку (параметр конструктора и оператора присваивания) невозможно привязать ко временному объекту (к результату `foo()`).

В такой ситуации мы можем попробовать "выкрутиться" за счет введения промежуточного класса, который мы назовем `Sref`, и который умеет только ссылаться на наш класс `S`

```
struct S;

struct Sref 
{
  S &s;
};
```

Добавим в наш класс `S` оператор конверсии к `Sref`, порождающий `Sref`-ссылку на самого себя

```
struct S
{
  ...
  operator Sref() 
  { 
    Sref r = { *this }; 
    return r; 
  } 
  ...
};
```

А также добавим в наш класс `S` конвертирующий конструктор из типа `Sref` и аналогичный конвертирующий оператор присваивания, которые ведут себя в соответствии с требуемой нам семантикой, но через ссылку `Sref`

```
struct S
{
  ...
  S(Sref sr) : i(sr.s.i)
    { sr.s.i = -1; }

  S& operator =(Sref sr)
  {
    i = sr.s.i;
    sr.s.i = -1;
    return *this;
  }
  ...
};
```

и готово - теперь инициализация и присваивание

```
S a = foo();

S b;
b = foo();
```

будет прекрасно компилироваться и работать именно так, как мы хотим. Они пойдут по пути

```
S a(foo().operator Sref());

S b;
b = foo().operator Sref();
```

Здесь также эксплуатируется то "странноватое" свойство языка, согласно которому хоть к временным объектам и нельзя привязывать неконстантные ссылки, через временные объекты однако можно вызывать их неконстантные методы.

---

Именно так работает и именно эту роль играет класс `auto_ptr_ref` в реализации функциональности `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: интересно кто додумался до такого, для меня придумать такой способ это космос.